# rename file names with recursion with variable

Tags: sed, mv

i have files in folders (git)  titled like this

```
 OrderReturnPartial_EN_${et.mode}.html
```

how can I rename all files in dir (and inner folders)

```
OrderReturnPartial_EN_${et.mode}.html
OrderReturnPartial_EN_my_mode.html
```

My try is like this

in the begging there's a var

```
read newmode
default="et.mode"

find /tmp/$newmode -name "*et.mode*" -print | while read FNAME;
do
mv "$FNAME" "${FNAME//$default/$newmode}";
done
```

also i tried

```
sed -i 's/{et.mode}/$newmode/g' $FNAME
```

doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The `mv` command should rename  `OrderReturnPartial_EN_${et.mode}.html` to `OrderReturnPartial_EN_${my_mode}.html` when `newmode=my_mode`.

Comment: no, I need another way

Comment: i need rename files _EN_${et.mode}.html to _EN_my_mode.html

Comment: Then set `default='${et.mode}'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `${et.mode}`, use the full string as the variable value:

```
default='${et.mode}'
f='OrderReturnPartial_EN_${et.mode}.html'
echo "${f//$default/my_mode}"
```